# jQuery hide li based on the id from nested ul li

Tags: jquery, nested-lists

I need to hide the specific li (with id= 3-DELETED-) from nested ul li based on the id field.

Example:

```js
The jquery I used:

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul li").each(function () {
     var id = $(this).attr("id");
     if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf('-deleted-') >= 0) {
         $(this).hide();
     }
 });
});
</script>
```

```html
<ul>
    <li id="1">New</li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li id="2">option1: blue</li>
            <li id="3">option2: green</li>
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li id="4">option 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li id="5-DELETED-">option3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

So, I am wondering if there is a way to hide the specific list item from the nested list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you have some li's without id so it crashes, try this instead

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("ul li").each(function () {
     var id = new String ($(this).attr("id"));
     if (id.toLowerCase().indexOf('-deleted-') >= 0) {
         $(this).hide();
     }
 });
});
```

Comment: I tried var id = this.id I also returned empty string when the id is not given.